# Tracking changes made to a NSManagedObject on a different thread

Tags: multithreading, core-data

I want to send changes made to any `NSManagedObject` to a server and I want to do this in background.

Therefor, I would like to setup a background thread with its own `NSManagedObjectContext` that registers for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. However, I cannot access `changedValues` on `userInfo`'s `NSInserted/Updated/DeletedObjectsKey`, because it's on a different thread.

How can this be done then?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is: don't bother with `changedValues`. Just send all attributes of any managed object that changes. The overhead is usually not very much, and your code will be simpler.

If you really want to send only the values of attributes that have changed, it gets more complicated:

- You **can** use `changedValues`, so long as you are using `NSMainQueueConfinement` or `NSPrivateQueueConfinement` **and** you call `changedValues` using `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` with a block that gets the changes. Get the changed values and copy them to something outside of Core Data. Make sure that all access to anything from Core Data is in one of those blocks. However `changedValues` is useless after a save, so...
- If you use `changedValues`, you'll need to use `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` to get notified of changes, but that can happen a lot, so...
- It's probably better to use `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`, which only happens when you're actually saving changes. There's no `userInfo` so you'll have to look at the notification's `object` (which will be an `NSManagedObjectContext`) and then use `insertedObjects`, `updatedObjects`, and `deletedObjects` to find out what objects have changed.

With this, you can access the changed values, copy them to whatever data structure you're using to hold outgoing changes, and then send them.

But I'd go with ignoring `changedValues` if it's at all possible.

Comment: How do I get the changed object from the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` as it's not passing any [`userInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification)?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed now.